# operator class "gin_trgm_ops" does not exist for access method "gin"

Tags: python, django, indexing, pytest-django, pg-trgm

`psycopg2.errors.UndefinedObject: operator class "gin_trgm_ops" does not exist for access method "gin"`

Hello everybody, this is the whole message when I try to run pytest on my project which is written in Python/Django + db is postgresql and all sitting inside docker.

I build a project on docker with django-cookiecutter template, all settings are default. I put a gin index to one of my string fields, migrations running successfully, `pg_trgm` extention is being created successfully, but if I try to test my project with pytest I got this error.

Here is my `pytest.ini`

```
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = config.settings.test
```

Here is my test settings file's database configuration: `test.py`

```
DATABASES['test'] = { # noqa
    'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
    'NAME': 'test',
    'PASSWORD': 'test',
    'USER': 'test',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': 5454,
}
```

This is part of the migration which creates the extention `pg_trgm` and puts an index to the field given

```
migrations.AddIndex(
            model_name='<model_name>',
            index=django.contrib.postgres.indexes.GinIndex(fields=['field_name'], name='field_name_gin_idx', opclasses=['gin_trgm_ops']),
        ),
```

And this is the whole traceback which I am getting:

```
self = <django.db.backends.utils.CursorWrapper object at 0xffff7244dbb0>
sql = 'CREATE INDEX "bank_name_gin_idx" ON "financing_graincreditagrobankworksheet" USING gin ("bank_name" gin_trgm_ops)', params = None
ignored_wrapper_args = (False, {'connection': <django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis.base.DatabaseWrapper object at 0xffff7d096b80>, 'cursor': <django.db.backends.utils.CursorWrapper object at 0xffff7244dbb0>})

    def _execute(self, sql, params, *ignored_wrapper_args):
        self.db.validate_no_broken_transaction()
        with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
            if params is None:
                # params default might be backend specific.
>               return self.cursor.execute(sql)
E               psycopg2.errors.UndefinedObject: operator class "gin_trgm_ops" does not exist for access method "gin"

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py:82: UndefinedObject

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

request = <SubRequest '_django_setup_unittest' for <TestCaseFunction test_correct_insurance_company_name>>
django_db_blocker = <pytest_django.plugin._DatabaseBlocker object at 0xffff7fe702b0>

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="class")
    def _django_setup_unittest(
        request,
        django_db_blocker: "_DatabaseBlocker",
    ) -> Generator[None, None, None]:
        """Setup a django unittest, internal to pytest-django."""
        if not django_settings_is_configured() or not is_django_unittest(request):
            yield
            return
    
        # Fix/patch pytest.
        # Before pytest 5.4: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/5991
        # After pytest 5.4: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django/issues/824
        from _pytest.unittest import TestCaseFunction
        original_runtest = TestCaseFunction.runtest
    
        def non_debugging_runtest(self) -> None:
            self._testcase(result=self)
    
        try:
            TestCaseFunction.runtest = non_debugging_runtest  # type: ignore[assignment]
    
>           request.getfixturevalue("django_db_setup")

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytest_django/plugin.py:490: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytest_django/fixtures.py:122: in django_db_setup
    db_cfg = setup_databases(
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/test/utils.py:179: in setup_databases
    connection.creation.create_test_db(
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py:74: in create_test_db
    call_command(
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py:181: in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py:398: in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py:89: in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py:244: in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py:117: in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py:147: in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py:227: in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py:126: in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py:761: in database_forwards
    schema_editor.add_index(model, self.index)
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/schema.py:218: in add_index
    self.execute(index.create_sql(model, self, concurrently=concurrently), params=None)
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py:145: in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py:66: in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py:75: in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py:84: in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py:90: in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <django.db.backends.utils.CursorWrapper object at 0xffff7244dbb0>
sql = 'CREATE INDEX "bank_name_gin_idx" ON "financing_graincreditagrobankworksheet" USING gin ("bank_name" gin_trgm_ops)', params = None
ignored_wrapper_args = (False, {'connection': <django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis.base.DatabaseWrapper object at 0xffff7d096b80>, 'cursor': <django.db.backends.utils.CursorWrapper object at 0xffff7244dbb0>})

    def _execute(self, sql, params, *ignored_wrapper_args):
        self.db.validate_no_broken_transaction()
        with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
            if params is None:
                # params default might be backend specific.
>               return self.cursor.execute(sql)
E               django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: operator class "gin_trgm_ops" does not exist for access method "gin"

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py:82: ProgrammingError
```

I want to run tests with pytest and got this problem which is actually not causing any problem while project is running, gin index is actually working. But only when I run a test no matter its django's `manage.py test` or  `pytest` it fails with the error above. If I comment out the part of migration which should generate an index it works.

Comment: You need to install the gin module on PostgreSQL.

Comment: I have installed it already, If I check extention list, or try to create one, It says extention has already been created. I did not work only in tests

Comment: the thet creates a new database with `_test` as suffix, so it needs to be installed/enabled on the test database as well.